# Copy Contents of One Column Of a Table To another of a different Table SQL

Tags: sql, pyodbc

I want to copy the content of one column in table A and replace the contents (not insert into it - the number of rows will be the same) of another column in another table.

I can't a where condition, the table has only just been created at this point with one empty timestamp column. it will be populated via pyodbc class after the timestamps have been added - this query will fill the timestamps for me

What is the SQL command for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: sending queryies over pyodbc to a windows sql db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion, this is the query needed : `INSERT INTO OCAT_test_table (DateTimeStamp) SELECT DateTimeStamp FROM DunbarGen`

Comment: I can't use id, the table has only just been created at this point with one empty timestamp column. it will be populated via pyodbc class after the timestamps have been added - this query will fill the timestamps for me

Comment: @MarkCorrigan How do you want to link both tables ? Is the value the same for every row in TableA ?

Comment: yes, same timestamps then scaled data to fill the new table

Comment: @MarkCorrigan If the value is the same for every row in TableA, just do : UPDATE TableB SET TableB.ColumnA=(SELECT ColumnA FROM TableA). No need for a where.

Comment: @MarkCorrigan it all depends on the DBMS you use (you are saying Windows SQL DB, but this could be Access, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.) and the table structures. But this is the basic concept.

Comment: what's a dbms? i'm writing a pyodbc class which interacts with a remote sql server with a selected database on it

Comment: @MarkCorrigan DBMS = Database Management System (the type of database can change the way you write the query a little bit). Have you tried a query like the solution I proposed ?

Comment: yep, it doesn't seem to work. the isql command does not fail - just nothing has been altered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58502/discussion-between-simon-and-mark-corrigan).